# Python required list parameter is not present

Tags: python, list, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to imitate the following cURL command to POST my url-encoded list to a form:

`curl "https://website.com/update/" --data "simChangesList=%5B%7B%22simId%22%3A760590802%2C%22changeType%22%3A2%2C%22targetValue%22%3A%220003077%22%2C%22effectiveDate%22%3Anull%7D%5D" --compressed`

The data I need to url-encode is the simChangesList. Essentially, this data is decoded as `simChangesList: [{"simId":760590802,"changeType":2,"targetValue":000307,"effectiveDate":null}]`

With the following script, I come across a `Required List parameter 'simChangesList' is not present` error.

Here's my script:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
enc = urllib.quote('simChangesList: [{"simId":760590802,"changeType":2,"targetValue":000307,"effectiveDate":null}]')
auth = session.post(uri, data=enc, headers=headers)
print auth.text
```

However, executing the above script returns the above missing list parameter error.

How can I pass in the missing list parameter when my encoded list looks like this:

```
simChangesList%3A%20%5B%7B%22simId%22%3A760590802%2C%22changeType%22%3A2%2C%22targetValue%22%3A000307%2C%22effectiveDate%22%3Anull%7D%5D
```

Notice it's missing the '=' operator, why can I not execute my script and make it closely resemble my cURL command to post my url-encoded information?

Comment: You're quoting a string starting with "simChangesList: ", so that's what you get. No = will appear. From the looks of it you're using the requests package. Pass a dict as data with "simChangesList" as key and the **unquoted**, but serialized list as value. You should not need to pass the header explicitly either.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Like this? `data = {simChangesList: 'simId': 760590802, 'changeType': 2, 'targetValue': '0003077', 'effectiveDate': 'null'}` I still can't seem to get it right, how should I format my list that i need to POST?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar situation landlord, but I just prompted one of the parameters inside json does not exist, is looking for a solution.

On the landlord to pass parameters, it is recommended to add a `json.dumps (data)`

try it.